# R - ggplot axis number format - remove leading zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

what is the option/code to drop the leading zero from a R ggplot geom_bar axis?

i.e., I'd like 0.05 to appear as .05

All I can manage to find are built-in formats like percent, comma, etc.

thx!

Comment: It'a needing to be coerced to a character value at some point, so hit it with `sub("^0","", vec)`

Comment: I wonder if you can create a custom format with scales() package. I have done that to create percentage or other formats with my preferred set of decimal places. Then you can use it anywhere, such as plots, tables, labels etc.

Answer (score 3):

As a simple alternative inspired by the answer given by m.evans, dropping the leading zero can be be achieved quite easily using the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

dropLeadingZero <- function(l){
  str_replace(l, '0(?=.)', '')
}

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,2.5, by = 0.5), 
                     labels = dropLeadingZero)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that you can call into the `labels` bit of your plot:

```
#create reprex
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)

#write the function
dropLeadingZero <- function(l){
  lnew <- c()
  for(i in l){
    if(i==0){ #zeros stay zero
      lnew <- c(lnew,"0")
    } else if (i>1){ #above one stays the same
      lnew <- c(lnew, as.character(i))
    } else
      lnew <- c(lnew, gsub("(?<![0-9])0+", "", i, perl = TRUE))
  }
  as.character(lnew)
}
```

You can then just call this in your `ggplot` call. Example:

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,2.5, by = 0.5), 
                     labels = dropLeadingZero)
```